# Difference between javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization and javax.transaction.Synchronization

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0, jta

I am working on an EJB3 application with mainly stateless session beans (SLSB). They use container managed transactions (CMT).

I want the beans to be aware of the transactions (for logging, etc). I can implement the `javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization` to do this. I find that I can register a `javax.transaction.Synchronization` in a default interceptor also to get similar callbacks.

Are there any dis/advantages to using one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple SLSB of the same type can be involved in the same transaction.  As soon as a method exits, the SLSB is returned to a pool for use by the next invocation, so it is not safe for an SLSB instance to be "aware" of a transaction: by the time it is notified, the bean might be in use in another transaction.

As for SFSB, I would say there is no advantage between the two approaches in theory.  However, the EJB container might be using Synchronization for various internal tasks, so using SessionSynchronization would allow the EJB container to have more control over the timing of the callbacks with respect to its own operations.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried to use the javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization interface with a stateless session bean and was confused not to get any calls of the three implemented methods. Then I saw this comment in the [javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html):

> Only a stateful session bean with container-managed transaction demarcation can receive session synchronization notifications. Other bean types must not implement the SessionSynchronization interface or use the session synchronization annotations.

See also [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/161691/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/SessionSynchronization-interface-stateless-session-bean) thread for some more background. So my conclusion is that making stateless session beans transaction-aware using CMT can NOT be achieved with javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization.