# Call a method on successful transaction in EJB 2.0

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-2.x

I have been working with ejb 2.0 for past 2 years on my application and suddenly stuck with a problem where I just want to call a method before and after transaction to database.

I am sure EJB 3.0 has interceptors to deal with this problem but any idea about EJB 2.0 that how to achieve it.

Comment: maybe using `Bean Managed Persistence`, so as you have total transaction control you can anything you want

Answer (score 0):

Your bean can implement the interface [`SessionSynchronization`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html). I think it's pretty old and was already in EJB 2.x.

Alternatively, there's `javax.transaction.Synchronization` and `javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` that you can use to register callback.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917717/difference-between-javax-ejb-sessionsynchronization-and-javax-transaction-synchr) discusses differences between the two; it seems to be unreliable to use `SessionSynchronization` for SLSB. I would recommend to read the relevant parts of the spec to understand precisely how they work.